# Typescript non-null assertion works differently when using NextJS

Tags: typescript, next.js, transpiler

According to typescript definition, using the non-null assertion operator never should impact execution, but I have a case where it, in fact, does.

My problem has been in replicating this with a simpler project. In my project, I have a fairly simple function:

```
const getNpcCharacterData = (npcMapConfig: IMapEntity | undefined): any => {
  return {
    position: {
      x: npcMapConfig?.position!.x ?? 0,
      y: npcMapConfig?.position!.y ?? 0,
    },
  };
};
```

Using the `!` causes an error if `npcMapConfig` is undefined. If I remove the `!`, there is no error. Looking at the generated javascript code, it is, in fact, different in these cases.

Without `!`:

```
return {
  position: {
    x: (_npcMapConfig_position_x = (_npcMapConfig = npcMapConfig) === null || _npcMapConfig === void 0 ? void 0 : _npcMapConfig.position.x) !== null && _npcMapConfig_position_x !== void 0 ? _npcMapConfig_position_x : 0,
    ...
```

Versus, with the `!`

```
return {
    position: {
        x: (_npcMapConfig_position_x = ((_npcMapConfig = npcMapConfig) === null || _npcMapConfig === void 0 ? void 0 : _npcMapConfig.position).x) !== null && _npcMapConfig_position_x !== void 0 ? _npcMapConfig_position_x : 0,
        ...
```

The difference is placement of parens, resulting in difference of when it is evaluating the `.x`. This seems unusual, new and unexpected.

This did not happen until recently when we updated from version 4.9.5 to 5.1.16. Generating for ES5 in both cases, identical tsconfig.json.

Unfortunately, I cannot get a small reproducible case. Every small case I create, the generated javascript is identical with or without `!`. It must be something else in my project, but something that impacts the conversion from ts -> js, which seems limited. It isn't a local issue, as it occurs in our CICD builds as well as local debug builds.

What I'm looking for an answer to is what else could impact this. `Webpack` is my biggest suspicion, but my understanding is that runs after the conversion to javascript, so while it might change the js, how would the `!` change it since that is removed prior? We are also using next-js, and I'm trying to reproduce without that to get a simple case. There is es-lint, but I don't think that impacts the transpilation.

Also, in my smaller cases, it only uses 2 temporary variables, one for _x and one for _y, but in the problematic code, it is also using a temp variable for the parameter itself (`_npcMapConfig`).  I am unsure why it would use a temporary for that, so any tsconfig settings that might lead to more aggressive use of temp variables or optimizations could be key, although I've been trying with identical tsconfig.

Comment: I'm not sure how to suggest you isolate this, but it's interesting that the combination of optional chaining and the non-null assertion error has some weird ambiguity of behavior as discussed in [ms/TS#36031](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/36031).

Comment: Thank you, @jcalz, that link is helpful. I've discovered that next-js recently changed to use their own typescript transpiler, so I think the issue is there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, by using `next-js`, the compiler used is not `tsc` but `swc`.
The behavior is easily reproduced when using `swc` as the transpiler.

I am changing the title of this question so this answer may help others in future.